# What is Fabric API Key?

Tags: android, twitter

As we create our app at dev.twitter.com/apps

We get below details:-

> Consumer Key (API Key)
>
> Consumer Secret (API Secret)

So where is the FABRIC KEY ?

In android manifesto file we have to use this FABRIC KEY

### android manifesto file:-

```
<meta-data     android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"     android:value="xxxxxxxxx" />
```

So please help me.

How can we get FABRIC KEY ?

Comment: Found!!!!!! :P  it here https://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-get-fabric-api-key-and-fabric-api-secret/

Answer (score 15):

If you’re looking for your API key or build secret, select your org on the https://www.fabric.io/settings/organizations, and click on the API Key and Build Secret links right underneath your org’s name.

Comment: That no longer works. Fabric is now moving to Firebase. Not sure how to do this now.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have login to Fabric go to https://fabric.io/kits/android/twitterkit/install
and scroll down and see the section **Add Your API Key** from here you can ***copy your API Key***

[image: Refer Image]

Answer (score 1):

To get fabric api key you need to install fabric plugin from settings-->plug ins
then restart android studio then press fabric icon
complete the wizard to get a list of fabric services 
choose crachlytics and install it after accepting terms of crachlytics

then it will ask you to make changes to your manifest and java file and build.gradle

ignore changes of build.gradle if you have already set it and ignore changes to the java file if you do not want to use the crachlytics but apply the changhes to your manifest file

these changes include the Internet permission if you have not already added it and includes the fabric api key that you need to add

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to install the ionic plugin

- To find them log to the https://www.fabric.io and go tho the app set
  up.
- Be sure to check the Apple icon.
- Then look for 3. Add your API Key.
- use them like `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-fabric-plugin --variable FABRIC_API_KEY=ec...5 --variable FABRIC_API_SECRET=9a...173e`

You will find them there.

[image]