# How to get io.fabric.ApiKey?

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am getting below error but I am not able to figure out how can I get the api key for io.fabric.ApiKey.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fabric could not be initialized, API key missing from AndroidManifest.xml. Add the following tag to your Application element 
        <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ApiKey.logErrorOrThrowException(ApiKey.java:110)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ApiKey.getValue(ApiKey.java:61)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.Settings.initialize(Settings.java:78)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.retrieveSettingsData(Onboarding.java:124)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:99)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Onboarding.doInBackground(Onboarding.java:45)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:63)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.doInBackground(InitializationTask.java:28)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Fabric API Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292128/what-is-fabric-api-key)

Comment: @CodeREDInnovations, the solution mentioned on the page is outdated, after fabric got merged with firebase there should be new solution, Which I could not find.

Comment: Do care to leave a comment for downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebaser here -- the Fabric dashboard has been deprecated, which means you can no longer access the API key. You can upgrade from the Fabric SDK to the [Firebase Crashlytics SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android), which doesn't require the Fabric API key to identify your app but rather the google-services.json file.

Comment: Looks like if you want to use twitter sdk you need fabric, is there any alternative to it?

Comment: Which Twitter SDK are you referring to? Twitter used to be a part of the Fabric SDK/suite, but this was years ago. If you're referring to an API key for Twitter there should be different options now other than the Fabric key.

Comment: I see, I should follow https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/twitter-login, Let me try. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)